# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (while running unit tests)

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, runtime-error, pydev

I started getting this error in PyDev on eclipse luna, in Linux environment, after rebooting my computer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 846, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file post_worker.py, line 105
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 846, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file post_worker.py, line 105
```

It happens when I try to run unit tests, any one of them. Moreover, it only happens in the IDE, when I run the tests from the command line, I've got no issues.